# splitting a sentence and storing it in to array using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a long string which is a combination of html tags and normal words and symbols.

for example, consider,

```
var k= '<html><div id="test">it is interesting, but I love you.</div></html>'
```

I am trying to split this string and store it in to array, like

```
<html>
<div id="test">
it
is
interesting
,
but 
I 
love 
you
.
</div>
</html>
```

I know how to separate html tags and names, but I am having trouble with symbols like underscore, full stop, comas and semicolons..

my code looks like this

```
var k,a,rg=/(<.*?>)|(\S+?(?=[\s<]))/g;

k='<html><div id="test"> it is interesting</div></html>';
a=k.match(rg);
console.log(a); // ["<html>", "<div id="test">", "it", "is", "interesting", "</div>", "</html>"]
```

how do i separate the symbols with regex??

Comment: For what purpose you want to split that html? Maybe it would be easier to simply convert it to html and then use DOM methods to find and change element you want?

Comment: I am using it for word by word comparison and alter the html stylings..

Comment: I am taking the input using innerhtml and then I want to add the styling based on matched words..

Comment: As a side note, please be careful about using regexp parsing of HTML. There are a lot of corner cases when dealing with HTML (even if it's produced by yourself). HTML entities and UTF character encoding, for instance. Check this SO question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035825/split-string-by-html-entities.

Comment: Can you try this one? `var rg=/(<.*?>)|(\w+)|([\S+])/g;`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)() command?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that someone asks this question, here is a fiddle that I wrote yesterday that should do what you are asking:

```
function GetInnerTextAsArray(text) {
    var arr,
        tmp = document.createElement("DIV");

        tmp.innerHTML = text;
        text = tmp.textContext||tmp.innerText;

    arr = text.split(/[\s,;]);
    return arr;    
}​
```

Comment: this will split on spaces, which is not really what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Do you necessarily need the commas and periods if you are comparing _words_ only? Why not strip them first and then run that string through this function?

Comment: No I am just altering the stylings... the rest should remain the same..so I dont wna delete any from original content..